# Codeception: Keep a logged in state

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

I want to keep or run the login before most of my tests. But if I try to move the login code to _before it doesn't work since there is no webguy instance available to me.

What is the best way to keep the session between multiple tests? This is my code so far, would be glad to receive some help. I have googled and checked the documentation but I cannot find anything about session stuff.

```
<?php
use \WebGuy;

class ProductCest
{

    private $product_id = '1';

    public function _before()
    {
    }

    public function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function login(WebGuy $I) {
        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/auth/login');
        $I->fillField("//input[@type='email']", "username@email.com");
        $I->fillField("//input[@type='password']", "1234");
        $I->click('#signIn .submit');
        $I->wait(500);

        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/account');
    }

    /**
     * @depends login
     */
    public function chooseProduct(WebGuy $I) {
        $I->wantTo('go to products and choose one');
        $I->amOnPage('/?product=' . $this->client_id);
    }

}
```

Comment: the best way to keep the session between multiple tests - Do you mean like Google ? u want to keep session a live between 2 sites ? or Please more details for more understand

Comment: The idea of the test is to try all the steps each time. This is, your web guy needs to login each time a test is run, just as @sinisa-valentic's answers shows.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that the accepted answer is a way of accomplish it, but not the best. Doing that you'll always have to reproduce all the steps to log in into the system, when you only need to share the user session. I think that grabbing the session cookie and pass it through the required user logged tests is better. To do that, you create a login function, get the cookie, and make your tests depends on the login test first:

```
<?php
use \AcceptanceTester;

class testingCest
{
    private $cookie = null;

    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }


    // tests
    public function login(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('entrar al sistema');
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/admin/login');
        $I->fillField('user','perry');
        $I->fillField('pass','pass-perry');
        $I->click('Login');
        $I->see('You\'re logged!');
        $this->cookie   = $I->grabCookie('your-session-cookie-name');
    }

    /**
     * @depends login
     */
    public function listUsers(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->setCookie( 'your-session-cookie-name', $this->cookie );
        $I->amOnPage('/admin/users');
        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/admin/users/1');
    }

    /**
     * @depends login
     */
    public function listRols(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->setCookie( 'your-session-cookie-name', $this->cookie );
        $I->amOnPage('/admin/rols');
        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/admin/rols/1');
    }
}
```

That way, if the login test fails, you won't get the cookie, and you won't pass the other tests.

I prefer this `@depends` annotation instead of the `@before` proposed in the other answer, because if you use `@depends` you'll ALWAYS execute the code in the test before, and the tests will be only executed after the login.

### UPDATE

There exists another answer bellow, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41109855/1168804 that may also help you, as the framework for Codeception has evolved since the writing of this answer.

Comment: This should be accepted answer I think as it's much faster

Comment: this is much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: Now, I have a lot of different cepts - how can i share a single login over multiple cepts? I have 1 Cept for every "property" and its about 40 different properties that can be managed. This means i still have to log in 40 times if i run the complete suite.

Comment: @RobQuist, you modify the login and store the cookie in a session var that will be checked before doing the whole login. If the var is there, just skip the login, if not, go login. And then, you should share the login method among the different cepts: Either create a parent class or use a trait (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) with the login method in your classes.

Comment: Chococroc - I've explained my question a bit better here; https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2693 you mind taking a gander?

Comment: Just like to add that codeception includes a functionality specifically for this, save(load)SessionSnapshot: http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#Session-Snapshot

Comment: This IS the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**All earlier answers are old**, now it's done directly in _before method which takes Actor class as argument.

```
<?php

namespace Test\Api;

use ApiTester;

class TrainingCest
{
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->amLoggedInAs('kgkg');
    }

    public function _after(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testForLoggedInUser(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function anotherTestForLoggedInUser(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

}
```

**And if you want to log in just once for all CEST files**, you can use global Registry class implementing Registry design pattern (see https://dzone.com/articles/practical-php-patterns/basic/practical-php-patterns-0) along with some lazyloading. Here is working code for my api integration tests defined in Actor class (in my case ApiTester):

```
public function amLoggedInAs($userLogin)
{
    $I = $this;

    if (Registry::getInstance()->exists($userLogin)) {
        // get data from registry
        $storedUserData = Registry::getInstance()->get($userLogin);
        $newAccessToken = $storedUserData['accessToken'];
        $playerId = $storedUserData['playerId'];
    }
    else {
        // no registry data - log in and save data in registry
        $I->tryToLogin($userLogin);

        $newAccessToken = $I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('data.newToken');
        $playerId = (int)$I->grabDataFromResponseByJsonPath('data.userId');
        Registry::getInstance()->set($userLogin, [
            'accessToken' => $newAccessToken,
            'playerId' => $playerId
        ]);
    }

    // finally set headers and some other data
    $I->haveHttpHeader('X-Token', $newAccessToken);
    $I->havePlayerId($playerId);
}

protected function tryToLogin($userLogin)
{
    $I = $this;

    $I->wantTo('login into api');
    $I->amGoingTo('try to log to API using login and password');
    $I->sendPOST('/system/login', ['login' => $userLogin, 'password' => self::getPassword($userLogin)]);

    // ...some other checking if user was correctly logged in ...
}
```

This code basically stores accessToken along with some additional data in Registry after user logged for first time. If another call to $I->amLoggedInAs('kgkg') is invoked, it gets these values from registry. You can have many logged users this way, each of them logged only once per suite.

You can use another method for autorization instead of custom token, logic will still be the same.

**Also if you're using WebDriver** (not PhpBrowser), you can use loadSessionSnapshot and saveSessionSnapshot instead of Registry to get quite the same result.

Comment: What is global Registry class in Codeception?

Comment: It's not a part of codeception. What I mean is Registry class implementing Registry design pattern. See https://dzone.com/articles/practical-php-patterns/basic/practical-php-patterns-0. Thanks for pointing that - updated my answer.

Comment: simply setting clear_cookies in yml file to false now seems to do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Right now Codeception takes care of this thanks to [saveSessionSnapshot](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#saveSessionSnapshot) and loadSessionSnapshot methods.

```
<?php
// inside AcceptanceTester class:

public function login($I)
{
     // if snapshot exists - skipping login
     if ($I->loadSessionSnapshot('login')) return;

     // logging in
     $I->amOnPage('/login');
     $I->fillField('name', 'jon');
     $I->fillField('password', '123345');
     $I->click('Login');

     // saving snapshot
     $I->saveSessionSnapshot('login');
}
?>
```

then in your test classes you just do it like this

```
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->login($I);
}
```

EDIT: since more people seem to have problem with the missing $I param, I updated my answer with `$I->login($I)`, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but in my case it only works if pass the parameter `$I->login($I)`

Comment: thank god for this answer, was losing hope in this framework.. surprising session info is not maintained by default.. this should be an option in a yml file somewhere

Comment: This totally saved my day! As written above, I had to accept the $I parameter in the login() function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
use \WebGuy;

class ProductCest
{

    private $product_id = '1';

    public function _before()
    {
    }

    public function _after()
    {
    }

    private function executeLogin(WebGuy $I){
        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/auth/login');
        $I->fillField("//input[@type='email']", "username@email.com");
        $I->fillField("//input[@type='password']", "1234");
        $I->click('#signIn .submit');
        $I->wait(500);
        return $I;
    }

    // tests
    public function login(WebGuy $I) {
        $I = $this->executeLogin($I);

        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('/account');
    }

    /**
     * @depends login
     */
    public function chooseProduct(WebGuy $I) {
        $I = $this->executeLogin($I);
        $I->wantTo('go to products and choose one');
        $I->amOnPage('/?product=' . $this->client_id);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do something similar like you showed me here but I failed before. Is there any way I could skip the first executeLogin to only be run when it's called by the other methods? I don't really need it to run as a test :)

Comment: You simply do not call the execute login method if you do not need to be logged in.

Comment: With this code, you'll always execute all the login steps any time you want to check pages with a logged user, which may be veeeery slow. I prefer share the session cookie and only run the test with @depends (see my answer below).

Comment: yes, there are better ways, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55596593/2075158

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, that if you work with SaveSessionSnapshot, you have to make sure that the function is called after your login is completely finished. Which means if your login takes some time (ldap-login or security checks) the SaveSessionSnapshot is executed before the login is finished and you save an empty session.
If so you have to tell your programm to wait ($I->wait()), or check if the login is finished completly.

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 in my case it was as simple as setting `clear_cookies` to **false** in .yml file..

Codeception deletes cookies between tests because you should stay logged in between tests as best practice.

But if you want to persist the cookie simply declare this:

```
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
              clear_cookies: false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Sinisa answer is a "working" one, but not the "correct" one.

What you want is not @depends annotation, but @before.

The difference is that with @depends the current context is not kept, while using @before keep the context.

```
public function foo(WebGuy $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/foobar');
}

/**
 * @depends foo
 */
public function bar(WebGuy $I)
{
    $I->seeInCurrentUrl('foobar'); // Wil fail
}

/**
 * @before foo
 */
public function baz(WebGuy $I)
{
    $I->seeInCurrentUrl('foobar'); // Will pass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that if you're testing WordPress, the WP-browser module has "sugar" methods for logging in:

```
loginAsAdmin();
loginAs($username, $password);
```

https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser